# Sending email from Office 365 non-default email addresses connected to a single account

Tags: vba, outlook, office365

VBA created emails are sent successfully, however I can only send from the email address of the default account.

As I have a few Office 365 connected email addresses, in Outlook 2016 I am able to manually select the 'FROM' out of the list of available connected email addresses.

In Outlook VBA, there is only one account (the exchange of Office 365), so using `SendUsingAccount` will find the one account.

`SentOnBehalfOfName` bounces on security issues. Is it possible to define the 'FROM' email address?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but you need to create the different accounts in Outlook. When done, use this code excerpt:

```
Dim SendAccount As String
SendAccount = "MyDesiredAccountName"

Set MAPISession = objOutlook.Application.Session 
Set MAPIMailItem = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)  'Create a new mail message

'**********************************************
'* Find desired from-account
'* If not found, use default
'*
For Each Account In MAPISession.Accounts
  If Account = SendAccount Then
    MAPIMailItem.SendUsingAccount = Account
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

Is this enough to get you started?

Comment: Thanks peakpeak. That's a working solution indeed. But i would prefer to have an outlook with only one account.

Comment: "In Outlook 2016 i am able to select the send 'FROM' out of the list of available connected accounts. That is not possible in VBA. In Otutlook, there is only 1 account."

please elaborate ... Outlook and Outlook